# Set up additional swap space as non-privileged user

Tags: swap, virtual-memory, privileges

I want to run a program that requires more memory than what is available on the target machine. Unfortunately, I do not have root access to the machine where the program runs, so I cannot set up a classical swap file (dd + mkswap + swapon).

Is there any other way that would allow the program to run, without the aid from super-user?

Comment: On a generic Unix system? No.

Comment: @Kusalananda In theory you could `LD_PRELOAD` a replacement for malloc and friends that map a file into memory instead of allocating memory from the OS. But that sounds complicated and slow.

Comment: @Gilles Your comment set me on the right path! While I have the sources of the program, the memory consumption is due to a (complex) external numerical library that I do not have the guts to explore. But the library accepts a user-allocated workspace, which in turn can be allocated on disk via mmap.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to create virtual machines as unprivileged user then you may set up an environment with enough swap space.